# SQLAlchemy: Self-referencial many-to-many relationship on subclasses

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my `SQLAlchemy` model shown below, users and groups are subclasses of a common subject class that contains, among other things, the ID.
A user can refence several groups.
However, when I add a group to a user, I get following database error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) FEHLER:  NULL-Wert in Spalte »user_id« von Relation »users_groups« verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
DETAIL:  Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (null, user1)

[SQL: INSERT INTO users_groups (group_id) VALUES (%(group_id)s)]
[parameters: {'group_id': 'user1'}]
```

My code looks like this:

```
import enum
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, create_engine, Integer, ForeignKey, ForeignKeyConstraint, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, drop_database, create_database
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

Base = declarative_base()

class AuthorizableType(enum.Enum):
    USER = 'USER'
    LINK = 'LINK'
    GROUP = 'GROUP'
    SUBJECT = 'SUBJECT'

authorizable_type_enum = postgresql.ENUM(AuthorizableType, name='authorizable_types')


class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'

    id = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    authorizable_type = Column(authorizable_type_enum, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': authorizable_type}


class UserGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users_groups'
    user_id = Column(String(30), ForeignKey('subjects.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(String(30), ForeignKey('subjects.id'), primary_key=True)


class User(Subject):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': AuthorizableType.USER}

    user_name = Column(String(50))
    groups = relationship('Group', back_populates='users',
        secondary='users_groups',
        foreign_keys='[users_groups.c.user_id]'
    )

class Group(Subject):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': AuthorizableType.GROUP}

    group_name = Column(String(50))
    users = relationship('User', back_populates='groups',
        secondary='users_groups',
        foreign_keys='[users_groups.c.group_id]'
    )


db_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/polytest'

if database_exists(db_url):
    drop_database(db_url)

create_database(db_url)

db_engine = create_engine(db_url)

Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine, autocommit=False)

db_session = Session()

group1 = Group(id='group_A', group_name='group_A')
db_session.add(group1)
group2 = Group(id='group_B', group_name='group_B')

user1 = User(id='user1', user_name='user1')
db_session.add(user1)

db_session.commit()

user1.groups.append(group1)
user1.groups.append(group2)

db_session.commit()
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Code snippet is working out of the box now. Sorry.